# Date change when save from Java (Hibernate) to Oracle 11g R2

Tags: java, hibernate, date, oracle11g, jodatime

I have a scheduler that run after midnight (around 1 am), to move data from Redis to Oracle. To get the actual date from yesterday I used JodaTime and substract the date by 1 day, the code looks like this

```
    DateTime today = new DateTime();
    logger.info("today date = {}", today);

    DateTime dateTimeMinus1 = today.minusDays(1);
    logger.info("today dateTimeMinus1 = {}", dateTimeMinus1);
```

And the logger output like this :

```
today date = 2015-02-13T01:13:00.073+07:00
today dateTimeMinus1 = 2015-02-12T01:13:00.073+07:00
```

after that I convert the JodaTime object to java.util.Date and set a property on a Java object (don't ask why, this is the requirement) using code like this :

```
myObject.setTxDate(dateTimeMinus1.toDate());
```

and then I save `myObject` to Oracle 11g R2 database using Hibernate, the mapping look like this

```
<property name="txDate" column="TX_DATE" type="timestamp" not-null="false"  />
```

As you can see from log output above the `dateTimeMinus1` is print the correct date (12 Feb 2015 1:13 AM) but when I query the date in Oracle in change to `11-02-2015 18:13:00`

I check the timezone between the apps server and db server, both of them set to same timezone (+07:00)

Any ideas what that could have been change the date when it's saved to database ?

Answer (score 0):

While quering to DB whatever format it may show, but when it comes to java it always shows the default format(ie. Fri Feb 13 14:42:01 IST 2015) irrespective of the DB format.

To solve this, you need to make use of SimpleDateFormat.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    Date today = new Date(); 
    System.out.println("Original date: "+today);
    String date = sdf.format(today);
    System.out.println("Formatted date: "+date);
```

Output is:

```
    Original date: Fri Feb 13 14:42:01 IST 2015
    Formatted date: 13-02-2015 02:42:01
```

Comment: I'm sorry for being not clear, what I meant is not the format like "dd-mm-yyyy" or something like that, I query the Oracle from Oracle client application like SQL Developer or TOAD, and the result is differ 1 day from the log output, in the database it shows 11 Feb, the log output shows 12 Feb